# Pipe stream with a delay without loosing data

Tags: node.js, stream, pipe

I try to pipe streams with a "delay".

The problem is, as soon as the input stream receives data, and the pipeing is done, the data is lost and nothing received on the output stream.

```js
const { PassThrough } = require("stream");

console.log("Started...");


const input = new PassThrough();
const output = new PassThrough();


output.on("data", (data) => {
    console.log("Chunk on output input", data);
});


input.on("readable", () => {

    console.log("input is readable, pipe to output");

    // this does not work 
    //setTimeout(() => {
    //    input.pipe(output);
    //}, 1000);

    // this dosnt work either
    // input.pipe(output);

});


// wait some time to simluate user input 
setTimeout(() => {
    console.log("Write to input");
    input.write(`Hello World ${Date.now()}`);
}, 1000);
```

How can i pipe streams with a delay without loosing data?

I thought the input stream is "buffered" till its drained, from a `.read`, pipeing or when switched into flow mode with the "data" event.

Any hint is welcomed.

---

EDIT:

Seems like the "readable" event listener is messing this up.
The example following example works, not sure why its not working within the readable event. There is nothing written in the docs that you must consume any data if the event is fired.

```js
const { PassThrough } = require("stream");

console.log("Started...");


const input = new PassThrough();
const output = new PassThrough();


output.on("data", (data) => {
    console.log("Chunk on output input:", data);
});


// wait some time before pipe
setTimeout(() => {
    console.log("Pipe input to output")
    input.pipe(output);
}, 2000);


// wait some time to simluate user input 
setTimeout(() => {
    console.log("Write to input");
    input.write(`Hello World ${Date.now()}`);
}, 1000);
```

I let this question open.
Perhaps some one has a explanation why the first example is not working with the readable event.

Comment: The deal with the `readable` event is that once you've gotten that event, it won't fire again until more data arrives or perhaps until you've read the data that is there.  So, if you wait until the `readable` event has fired before you configure the `.pipe()` and the `.pipe()` perhaps uses the `readable` event, then it may not get that event and may never realize there is data to be read.

Comment: We could probably help you better if we knew what real problem you were trying to solve because these approaches are probably not the right approach to whatever the real problem is.  We may be able suggest alternate approaches if we better understand the underlying problem you're trying to solve.  Why the delay?

Answer (score 0):

You should pipe input to output immediately, you don't have to wait:

```
const { PassThrough } = require("stream");

console.log("Started...");

const input = new PassThrough();
const output = new PassThrough();

input.pipe(output);

output.on("data", (data) => {
  console.log("Chunk on output input:", data);
});

// wait some time to simluate user input
setTimeout(() => {
  console.log("Write to input");
  input.write(`Hello World ${Date.now()}`);
}, 1000);
```